# fetch ajax from javascript function

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I called ajax (which return json data) from a javascript function like below

```js
function getDataSets(groupID)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
  dataType: "json",
        url: 'del/deljson.php',
  data:'groupID='+groupID,
        success:function(msg){
   //alert(msg);
   return msg; 
        }
    });
}
```

when i call this function as alert(getDataSets(1)); it return "undefined". However if i call alert on success of ajax it shows return data. what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The return inside the `success` is only for that function. Try to take a variable inside the function (outside of the Ajax call) and then set the variable inside the ajax call. And return it at the end of the function.

Comment: i did this:  function getDataSets(groupID)
{
 var json="";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
  dataType: "json",
        url: 'del/deljson.php',
  data:'groupID='+groupID,
        success:function(msg){
    json=msg;
        }
    });
return json; 
}
 but still no success

Comment: Check this link as suggested : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call